# jquery - select last div on the click width

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, viewport

We have many `divs` on the page (see demo below). The container width of `divs` is not fixed.

How to select the last `DIV` in the line if user made click on some `DIV` in the line with jquery?

demo of html:
http://jsfiddle.net/F7xHa/

Text Illustration:   ( `#` - is div, X - clicked `div`, `S` - need to select this DIV with jquery)

```
# # # # # - line
# X # # S - line with click
# # # # # - line
# # # # # - line
```

**The idea (maybe not the best):** 
1. When user click on some `DIV` (marked X), need to get somehow offset from the top of the page to click position. (width of click on the screen)
2. Then select somehow all visible elements up to click position width)
3. select `:last` of them.

And maybe it's will help: Im already know how to select the last visible DIV on the page. I use inViewport‎ plugin. But now the task is much harder.

Comment: I think that question has been asked already.

Comment: and deleted because no examples and nobody understand the question. now its with html example. and forgive me my language. maybe somebody can edit the question to make it clean?

Comment: I does not know how to define the line of `divs` - it can change if the size of browser window changed.

Comment: you have nicely improved question

Comment: @A.Wolff thank you. you can also edit it to make it better. (maybe I made some spelling mistakes. I'm not sure about the line where I define the line (hard to explain).

Comment: You have an issue in that you don't have any element defining a "line". The `div`s break over to the next line as the container's width varies. Can you wrap those individual `div`s in a containing element?

Comment: @ChrisHardie yes, I know that it's not wrapped like a `line` with any other elements. It's the question how to find the line... It's dynamic. I assume that we can find the line from the click position with some offset of `DIV` height

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about something like this:

```
$('.img').on('click', function(){
    var $self = $(this),
        elements = [],
        selfOff = $self.offset().top;
    $('.img').each(function(){
        if($(this).offset().top == selfOff){
            elements.push($(this))
        }
    })
    elements[elements.length-1].addClass('last')
})
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/F7xHa/2/)

Might be a better option, but can't think of another one at the moment.
This will select only the last one!

If you need to select the elements between the current and the last:

```
$('.img').on('click', function(){
    var $self = $(this),
        elements = [],
        selfOff = $self.offset().top;
    $('.img').each(function(){
        if($(this).offset().top == selfOff){
            elements.push($(this))
        }
    })
    $self.nextUntil(elements[elements.length -1]).addClass('last')
})
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/F7xHa/4/)

Or if you like to select all the elements (with the clicked and the last):

```
$('.img').on('click', function(){
    var $self = $(this),
        elements = [],
        selfOff = $self.offset().top;
    $('.img').each(function(){
        if($(this).offset().top == selfOff){
            elements.push($(this))
        }
    })
    $self.nextUntil(elements[elements.length-1]).add($self).add(elements[elements.length-1]).addClass('last')
})
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/F7xHa/5/)

Comment: thanks! wow, you are very good at jquery coding. Seems 95% of visitors (like I) does not know how to make first variant, but you make two of them. Which one is better to use? Maybe some advantages and disadvantages? Or portability issues?

Comment: and also the question are all of them `safe` to use without jquery `.ready()` function. Seems the last one in the comment can make mistake if `dom` not ready, but user make the click?

Comment: For the solutions, both are good if you are using the same width and height of `img`, if you use different width, the @A. Wolff will not work correctly, if you use different height (the look will break if they are floated) mine won't work...About the `dom` each `code` is on `dom ready` look at left of the jsfiddle and you will see onDomready.

Comment: Thanks, I understand. I mean that I will use this codes without `dom ready` is it ok? So, I need immediately respond if some `DIV` loaded and user clicked.

Comment: I'm not quite following you. You can load the code on doc.ready or on doc.load, there is no other option.